# Fuzzy find bookmarks (including folders) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks

Is there a way (built-in or through a third-party extension) to do a fuzzy find on my Chrome bookmarks *and their folders*? I've been able to come pretty close with just the bookmarks, but it is limited to be unable to include parts of the folder tree in the search.

Seems like a simple need, but I've been unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Using The Atomic Bookmarks Extension To View & Search Chrome
    Bookmarks By Folder**

[Atomic Bookmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/atomic-bookmarks-2/njacljdblagcjdmljcgpjkcinfflmgdk) is a simple extension that lets you search within folders. From the list of bookmarks it displays in a popup, you can select which folders you want to search in. Here’s how to use it:

**2. Using EveryMark To Bookmark Instantly, Search Within Folders &
    Delete Bookmarks**

[EveryMark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/everymark/ccgmhgakppaknnnnbgkmpdlnpjokhcpb) is an extension that intends to respond as effectively as desktop-file-searching software Everything (which you don’t really have to even install). It displays your bookmarks in a nice popup just like Atomic Bookmarks but it offers additional features that Atomic doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Atomic Bookmarks 2 gets pretty close, though it's search isn't "fuzzy" or nested per se. However, it's sufficient for my needs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/details) extension.

> Vimium is a Chrome extension that provides keyboard-based navigation and control in the spirit of the Vim editor.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> lets you fuzzy search bookmarks. This doesn't work on a blank tab and on the occasional webpage (mostly pages like gmail).

Comment: Vimium looks awesome, but the fuzzy bookmark search appears to only work for the names of the bookmarks and does not seem to include bookmark folders.